# Как восстановить пароль от stackoverflow?

Tags: поддержка, авторизация

Здравствуйте забыла пароль от stackoverflow, доступ к аккаунту есть, но что-то в настройках не могу найти этой информации, как можно восстановить?

Comment: Профиль -> Настройки -> Ваши способы входа -> Сменить пароль
Для вас:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/513051

Comment: @void вот это я понимаю **прямая** ссылка. :)

Comment: @eccs0103, я как раз это и указал, когда голосовал за закрытие.